# ElasticSearch 5.1 Filtering by Comparing Arrays

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, filter

I have a keyword array field (say f) and I want to filter documents with an exact array (e.g. filter docs with f = [1, 3, 6] exactly, same order and number of terms).

What is the best way of doing this?

Regards

Comment: Why you want exactly same order?

Comment: I have the nodes of directed acyclic graph (DAG) structures represented as documents in elasticsearch where all of them have the same parent (i.e. a graph document) but each node has a field called parentNodeIds which is an array of ordered IDs of parents. Now, there is a requirement that the user search for the existence of leaf nodes with a specific path (i.e. an array of node IDs) ordered from the root parent node ID to the leaf node ID. I want to satisfy this requirement by filtering nodes with parentNodeIds matching exactly the given path array. Any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to add a script to the query which would also check the number of elements in the array.

it script would be something like

```
      "filters": [
      {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['f'].values.length == 3"
        }
      },
      {
        "terms": {
          "f": [
            1,
            3,
            6
          ],
          "execution": "and"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Hope you get the idea.

I think an even better idea would be to store the array as a string (if there are not many changes to the structure of the graph) and matching the string directly. This would be much faster too.